# Most efficient way to get index in a sorted vector in R?

Tags: r, performance, indexing, match

I have a sorted vector `x`, and a vector containing limits `L` (in increasing order with no specific assumptions), I want to store the max index for all limits in `x`. I have a solution but it seems inefficient.

What is the fastest way to perform this?

```
x = sort(runif(n = 1e6))
L = sort(runif(n = 100))
index = sapply(L, function(l) which.max(x>l))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findInterval` :

```
x = sort(runif(n = 1e6))
L = sort(runif(n = 100))
findInterval(L, x) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I did a test and `findInterval` seems to be extremely much faster, ~100 times.